# Objective-C syntax problem

Tags: objective-c

I am trying something very trivial here, but the program is terminating with a “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” in the NSLog. I am attempting to populate a mutable array with several dictionaries like this:

```
NSMutableArray *_recipientsMutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *r1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"firsValue", @"firstKey", @"secondValue", @"secondKey", nil];

[_recipientsMutArray addObject:r1];

[r1 release];
```

Why?

Comment: This code is fine! The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: You say it's crashing in a NSLog, but you didn't include code with one.

Comment: I think he means it is reporting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the console log.

Comment: it might be a good idea to post the stack trace and tell us which line it is crashing on.

Comment: The error was that I had integers and booleans as values in my dictionary. These were taken away to reduce the code in my example. With it, the problem disappeared. I apologize, and promise to test my example code in the future. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have provided is fine, and shouldn't cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, however you mention a crash with `NSLog`. A common mistake to make with `NSLog` is to provide a C-style string for the format string, rather than an `NSString`. The following will cause errors:

```
int i = 4;
NSLog("%d", i); // oh no!
```

Instead, you need to ensure that `NSLog`'s first argument is an `NSString`, like this:

```
int i = 4;
NSLog(@"%d", i); // yay!
```

Comment: Yup, I've spent a few hours on that one!